# LinkedIn Video Analytics timeRange

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to fetch video analytics by date range.

I followed Video Analytics API,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/video-analytics-api

But I get an error.

Didn't find any other reference in the Web.

It should be noted that I fetch lifetime data (without time range parameter) successfully and that `encodeURIComponent` didn't help.

The request:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/videoAnalytics?q=entity&entity=urn:li:ugcPost:6516733420171780096&type=VIEWER&aggregation=DAY&timeRange=(start:1553385600000,end:1553817600000)
```

The error:

```
{
   "message": "Parameter 'timeRange' is invalid",
   "status": 400
}
```

**Edit:**

using epoch - no error, but also **no metrics data**

even I got metrics in fetching lifetime, when fetching dateRange, and I tried several date ranges from video creation date until today - returns empty array.

```
{
   "elements": [],
   "paging": {
       "total": 0,
       "count": 10,
       "start": 0,
       "links": [],
    }
}
```

trying fetching ALL - to mimic lifetime - also returns empty array:

```
https:/api.linkedin.com/v2/videoAnalytics?q=entity&entity=urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A6516733420171780096&type=VIEWER&timeRange=(start:1552176000,end:1564012800)&aggregation=ALL
```

weird - even trying to get an error by switching start date and end date returns empty array.

Comment: If you add the Header "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" the error message will change in "Invalid query parameters passed to request"

Comment: I tried it but forgot to mention. Tanks. But still, I only followed the example request. So what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need epoch time, not miliseconds

Try replacing time with
start:1563969600,end:1564401600

Converter -> https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Thank you. But now I get only empty array. See edit.

Comment: @AmichayMiara All depends on api logic then. Can block too many requests or api has some limits ? can be no data in that range? may be missing some permissions ?

Comment: I don't think so, because when I use the endpoint without the fields dateRange,aggregation, I got lifetime data as expected...